# Selecting SPECIFIC next sibling of a parent sibling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to programming and making a one user blog app. A blog post can have comments. What I'm trying to do is to show the comments only after clicking on the "comment" of each post.
I'm able to do this in here.

```
$(".comment-area-toggle").click(function(){
$(this).next('.comment-area').slideToggle();

     <li style="margin: none !important;"> Likes: {{ entry.likes }} 
        <a href='/likes/{{entry.id}}/{{entry.likes}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
        <a href='/dislikes/{{entry.id}}/{{entry.likes}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="comment-area-toggle" style="cursor: pointer">Comments:</li> 
      <div class="comment-area">
          <form class="comment-box" action="{{ url_for('add_comment')}}" method="post">
            <dl>
              <li>
                <dd><textarea style="width: 80%; vertical-align: bottom;" name="commenttext" placeholder="Add a comment..." rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
                <button id="comment" class="btn-comment" type="submit">Comment</button>
              </li>
              <dd><input type="hidden" name="commentid" value = {{entry.id}}>
            </dl>
          </form>
      {% for comment in commentonentries %}
        {% if entry.id == comment.comment_id %}
          <li style="color: rgb(70, 70, 70)">{{ comment.commenttext|safe }}</li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}        
      </div>
```

but not in this method.

```
$(".comment-area-toggle").click(function(){
$(this).parent().next('.comment-area').slideToggle();

      <li style="margin: none !important;"> Likes: {{ entry.likes }} 
        <a href='/likes/{{entry.id}}/{{entry.likes}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
        <a href='/dislikes/{{entry.id}}/{{entry.likes}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>
        <li class="comment-area-toggle" style="cursor: pointer">Comments:</li>
      </li>


      <div class="comment-area">
          <form class="comment-box" action="{{ url_for('add_comment')}}" method="post">
            <dl>
              <li>
                <dd><textarea style="width: 80%; vertical-align: bottom;" name="commenttext" placeholder="Add a comment..." rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
                <button id="comment" class="btn-comment" type="submit">Comment</button>
              </li>
              <dd><input type="hidden" name="commentid" value = {{entry.id}}>
            </dl>
          </form>
      {% for comment in commentonentries %}
        {% if entry.id == comment.comment_id %}
          <li style="color: rgb(70, 70, 70)">{{ comment.commenttext|safe }}</li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}        
      </div>
```

I want to be able to work with the second code because in the first code, the problem is I have to place the "comments" on the line below likes.
I want to place "comments" on the same line as likes (and i have tried bootstrap row-col method and it is not a nice solution)
Now in the second code, I think, (this).parent().next('.comment-area') should select the specific post's comment section, but it's not.
And the class "comment-area" has display: none so that it doesn't show up when the page loads

Comment: Only UL or OL is allowed to be a parent for LI.

Comment: try nextAll - it select all siblings, not only the first

Comment: Oh, that was helpful, thanks, I know what to do now :)